# Reading NFC into web application

Tags: javascript, nfc, webusb, webhid, webnfc

I am building a web application, which should read information from an NFC reader connected through USB. It is supposed to work on windows desktop and linux. I need a method similar to [Web NFC API](https://whatwebcando.today/nfc.html), which is great for my purpose.  Unfortunately, it is only for Android. They plan to support other platforms [in the future](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1zowdPEgg_EhIp17MWUg-OhI9VSHv9FXjMMiHCrAiASY/edit#heading=h.430ahftk4vy), but when?

The next option, I explored, was WebHID. See https://web.dev/hid. But my device ACR122U is not supported.

Then I tried WebUSB API, but with the same result as here and here.

> Failed to execute 'claimInterface' on 'USBDevice': The requested
> interface implements a protected class

. Here is [the reason](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/blink-dev/c/LZXocaeCwDw/m/GLfAffGLAAAJ).

I´ve read many posts here, but found no solution.

Is there any stable and robust solution (like Web NFC)?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you did everything right according to https://web.dev/devices-introduction/#discover,

1. Check Web NFC: It is supported on Android only for now.
2. Fallback to WebHID: ACR122U does not support HID.
3. And finally check WebUSB: Smart card interface access is blocked.

Your best bet is to wait for the potentially upcoming Smart Card Web API. Check out https://github.com/WICG/proposals/issues/64